# How to generate random but valid e164 numbers for testing?

Tags: rspec, faker

I'm currently using faker's `Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone`, the only problem is that I have a very strict e164 validation and some of the numbers generated do not pass e164 parsing. Is there an elegant way of faking random, yet valid e164 numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this and it works

```
  phone { Phonelib.parse(Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone_in_e164) }
```

I have a `faker.rb` initializer with:

```
Faker::Config.locale = 'en-US'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can override the formats for cell_phone in the locale to match the format you need.

Comment: Formatting doesn't matter, the validity of the number matters. In other words, i need something that generates a number that would pass an e164 validation. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/v8.4.1/resources/PhoneNumberMetadata.xml

Comment: @RyanRomanchuk I have this problem too! Did you make any headway?

Comment: @RyanRomanchuk there are many examples in Faker of formats that match very specific validation requirements -- that is the way to do it using Faker.

Comment: No there isn't, you are thinking of formatting validation, i am talking about *literal* phone number validation.  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/v8.4.1/resources/PhoneNumberMetadata.xml <--- something that passes this.  meaning if you use +1, the following 3 numbers *must* be a valid north american area code.  Faker definitely does not do this, it's very complex.

Comment: If you can specify a valid format as a regex, you can do it with Faker.  See https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/lib/locales/en/finance.yml as an example.